# How to input two arguments with getopts?

Tags: getopts

I am writing a simple bash script. My script installs [ppa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive). The problem is I can't add two arguments. I want to write something simple like this:

```
./ppa.sh -i ppa:chris-lea/node.js nodejs
```

I tried this,  but doesn't read the second argument 'nodejs'...

```
#! /bin/sh 
# Install/add PPA or Program 

while getopts ":i:e:" option;
do
 case $option in
  i)
   echo received -i with $OPTARG
ang='sudo apt-add-repository'
   ;;
  e)
   echo received -e with $OPTARG
ang='other line'
   ;;
  :)
   echo "option -$OPTARG needs an argument"
exit
   ;;
  *)
   echo "invalid option -$OPTARG" 
exit
   ;;
 esac

# done
    if [ "`echo $OPTARG | cut -d ':' -f1`" == "ppa" ]; then
echo 'is a ppa'
    $ang $OPTARG ; sleep 2s && sudo apt-get update; clear
        sudo apt-get -y install $OPTARG2
    fi
done
```

Comment: So `-i` takes two arguments?  How many does `-e` take?  Can they ever be mixed?

Comment: @Mikel `-e` will remove the ppa and uninstall the package

Comment: I  have solved it, and now work! only was necessary include a **new variable**: 
`OPTARG2=$( echo "$OPTARG" | awk '{ print $2 }')` and now work. 

**Also enclose with double quote:**

`./ppa.sh -i "ppa:chris-lea/node.js nodejs"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put two arguments in quote or double quote:

```
% ./ppa.sh -i 'ppa:chris-lea/node.js nodejs'
received -i with ppa:chris-lea/node.js nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks was necessary include a new variable: `OPTARG2=$( echo "$OPTARG" | awk '{ print $2 }')` and now work. And enclose the input with double quote `" "`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `-i` means install, and takes two arguments, it's probably easier to just set the `-i` flag in your getopts block, then treat the arguments remaining after option processing as the repo and package, e.g.

```
while getopts ":i" option; do
    case "$option" in
    i)
        mode=install
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

case "$mode" in
install)
    apt-add-repository "$1"
    apt-get update
    apt-get install "$2"
    shift 2
    ;;
esac
```

Or if the idea is to take a list of PPAs and packages, even more reason to do it this way, just make the last bit

```
case "$mode" in
install)
    for arg in "$@"; do
        case "$arg" in
            ppa:*)
                apt-add-repository "$arg"
                apt-get update
                ;;
            *)
                apt-get install "$arg"
                ;;
         esac
    done
    ;;
esac
```